# How would you find the unit normal vector to the surface $x+y^{2}+2z=4$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

What is the method that would be used to find the unit normal vector to the surface given by the equation $x+y^{2}+2z=4$?

Comment: That's not a plane.

Comment: Hint : The normal depends on the point you use (as this is not a plane there won't be a single normal vector that works for the entire surface).  As this is a level surface, $g(x,y,z)=c$, you can take the gradient of $g$ to get a normal vector.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{(x,y,z)\mid x+y^2+2z=4\}=\{u(y,z)=(y^2+4-2z, y,z)\mid y,z\in \mathbb R\}$$

I denote $u_y=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $u_z=\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$. A normal is given by $u_y\times u_z$.

Answer (score 0):

if you difference $x + y^2 + 2z = 4, $ and use the fact that $(dx, dy, dz)$ is tangent vector ay $(x, y, z),$ then you get $$0=dx + 2ydy + 2dz = (1,2y, 2)^\top \cdot (dx, dy, dz)^\top.$$ that is the normal vector at the point $(x,y,z)$ to the surface $x + y^2 + 2z = 4 $  is $(1,2y,z)^\top.$

Comment: Thanks. Would you then find $(1,2y,2)^{\top}$ using the scalar product?

Comment: @user2910074, you need to know the coordinates $(x, y, z)$ of the point at which the normal direction is required.

Comment: Okay, suppose those points were $(1,1,1)$. Then $(1,2y,2)$ becomes $(1,2,2)$. What now?

Comment: make the vector unit dividing $(1,2,2)$ by its length $\sqrt{5}$

Comment: So the normal vector at a point in a plane $(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ is just given in the same way you find the direction in which the gradient of the plane increases most rapidly at that point (i.e. by $\nabla f(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$)?

Comment: @user2910074, yes.